# How to send pdfs to a remote server using Java?

Tags: java

I want to send pdfs to a client webservice url using Java. How can this be done?

Comment: What technology do you use? Pure servlets? Axis? Jax-WS? ...

Comment: This depends very much on the specification of the web service.

Comment: What does 'client webservice url' even mean, especially considering that you want to push to a 'remote server'? Lazy questions are not going to get you any good answers.

Comment: @Abdullah: What do you think about my non lazy answer :D?

Comment: You assumed a lot about what OP wants... A+ for effort though :)

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly sorry, it's not a lazy question. That's how much I understood the problem myself. "client webservice url' was some server url that was provided to me and I was asked to upload pdfs using that url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few simple steps. I will add some terms between brackets for googling.

1. Open a FileInputStream for the pdf file. (java file inputstream)
2. Tell the server you will send a file.
3. Use a byte[] buffer and fill it from the inputstream and write it to the server. (java read inputstream buffer). You will have to tell the server what the size is of the coming buffer.

Here is some sample code.

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OuputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
int n;
byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 16];
while ((n = in.read(b)) != -1)
{
    dos.writeByte(1); // tell the server a buffer is coming
    dos.writeInt(n); // tell it the how big the buffer is
    dos.write(b, 0, n); // write the buffer
}
dos.writeByte(0); // tell the server no more buffers are coming.
dos.flush();
```

Now, it is up to you to write the server part of it.

Comment: Well, I think this is not an answer to your question... I think you want something else... But I'm not sure.

Comment: URL u = new URL(url);
 URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
uc.setDoOutput(true);
uc.setDoInput(true);
uc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
 DataOutputStream dstream = new DataOutputStream(uc.getOutputStream());

Comment: Defining the DataOutputStream object differently and then writing to it. Will that work?

Comment: I don't think so, because you didn't wrote the server side code yourself.